# Installation of ImageMagick software fails with "configure: error: libltdl is required"

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, compiling, imagemagick

I am trying to install ImageMagick in my Ubuntu 18.04.1, following the instructions in [this link](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-imagemagick-7-on-ubuntu-18-04-linux).

After running the following command

```
./configure
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
configure: error: in `/home/bharath/src/ImageMagick-7.0.8-66':
configure: error: libltdl is required for modules and OpenCL builds
See `config.log' for more details
```

Could anyone tell how to fix these errors?

Comment: Unless you specifically need a different version, you should probably install the pre-built binary `imagemagick` package from the Ubuntu repository instead of trying to build it from source

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As [steeldriver suggests in their comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1176044/intallation-of-imagemagick-software#comment1963396_1176044), it is recommended that you install `imagemagick` from the official Ubuntu repositories (`imagemagick` 6.9 for Ubuntu 18.04 - 20.10), by running:

```
sudo apt install imagemagick
```

However, if you still need to install `imagemagick` from source, just install the `libltdl` development package, as the error suggests, by running:

```
sudo apt install libltdl-dev
```