# Cannot install imagemagick in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: software-installation, imagemagick

I'm following [the instructions](https://www.tecmint.com/install-imagemagick-on-debian-ubuntu/).

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
wget https://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick.tar.gz
tar xvzf ImageMagick.tar.gz
cd ImageMagick-7.0.8-66/
```

I download the file, and after I do: `./configure`

Whatever I try I receive errors:

```
make
```

> make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

```
make install
```

> make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.

```
sudo make install
```

> make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.

What can I do?

### edit

I've tried `sudo apt-get install imagemagick`
and I get this error when trying to convert an image with `sudo apt install imagemagick`

> convert-im6.q16: delegate failed `'dwebp' -pam '%i' -o '%o'' @
>   error/delegate.c/InvokeDelegate/1919. convert-im6.q16: unable to open
>   file`/tmp/magick-26070kv4gJ8l8TYTt': No such file or directory @
>   error/constitute.c/ReadImage/600. convert-im6.q16: no images defined
>   `x.pdf' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1176044/installation-of-imagemagick-software-fails-with-configure-error-libltdl-is-re/1176071 for advice.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've tried that solution and it didn't worked... (I've updated my question showing what I've done and the error)

Comment: How could "to convert an image with `sudo apt install imagemagick`" possibly be expected to work? The command I've quoted is for installing it, not for using it. There are many tutorials for how to use imagemagick.

Comment: Two examples of using imagemagick to "convert" images: `convert temp.png -chop 214x614+86+614 tmp.png`, `convert checkbox-unchecked-insensitive.png -fuzz 75% -fill blue -opaque yellow checkbox-unchecked-insensitive2.png`. (`convert` is part of the imagemagick suite.)

Comment: I've meant `sudo apt-get install imagemagick`, and it seems to work, but then I've tried `convert x.jpg x.pdf` and the error appeared. And then I've tried `convert x.jpg x.png` and the exact same error. I've used in an older ubuntu imagemagick, and that simple convert command does work. Or I better say should work if the installation were ok.

Comment: Why wasn't imagemagick installed on your system to begin with? It's pretty deeply entangled into Ubuntu. And why not just install it from the repos? Are you actually running Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, I'm running Ubuntu 19.04. I's a fresh install, actually.